# How do I implement a trait for a struct when the trait requires more state than is contained in the struct?

Tags: oop, struct, rust, traits, composition

How do I implement a trait for a struct when the trait requires more state than is contained in the struct? For example, how would I implement the `Employee` trait for the `Human` struct shown below?

```
struct Human {
    name: &str,
}

trait Employee {
    fn id(&self) -> i32;
    fn name(&self) -> &str;
}

impl Employee for Human {
    fn id(&self) -> i32 {
        // From where do I get the ID?
    }
    fn name(&self) -> &str {
        self.name
    }
}
```

I'm not seeing any way to tuck additional state into the `impl` or into the trait.

Is the only option to create a new `HumanToEmployeeAdapter` struct holding the missing info and then implement the `Employee` trait for the new struct?

P.S. My background is in C#. Here's how I would approach it in that language:

```cs
class Human
{
    public string Name { get; }

    public Human(string name) { Name = name; }
}

interface IEmployee
{
    int Id { get; }
    string Name { get; }
}

class HumanToEmployeeAdapter : IEmployee
{
    readonly Human _human;

    public int Id { get; }
    public string Name => _human.Name;

    public HumanToEmployeeAdapter(
        Human human,
        int id)
    {
        _human = human;
        Id = id;
    }
}
```

You'll notice that this is the "create a new `HumanToEmployeeAdapter` struct" path. So, is this the way Rustaceans solve this problem?

Comment: Your background is C#, so if you implemented a C# interface with a method `GetId`, how would you provide it in this case?

Comment: *"How do I implement a trait for a struct when the trait requires more state than is contained in the struct"* => You can't. That's not what traits are for. You need to create another struct (which may be a wrapper type).

Comment: hint: rust wouldn't classify as OO.

Comment: Comments aren't the best place to get into this argument, but many of us (myself included) count Rust as an OO language. It does not have inheritance, but that's not required for OO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can translate your C# code almost exactly, something like this:

```
struct Human<'a> {
    name: &'a str,
}

trait Employee {
    fn id(&self) -> i32;
    fn name(&self) -> &str;
}

struct HumanToEmployeeAdapter<'a> {
    human: &'a Human<'a>,
    id: i32,
}

impl<'a> HumanToEmployeeAdapter<'a> {
    fn new(id: i32, human: &'a Human<'a>) -> Self {
        HumanToEmployeeAdapter { id, human }
    }
}

impl<'a> Employee for HumanToEmployeeAdapter<'a> {
    fn id(&self) -> i32 {
        self.id
    }

    fn name(&self) -> &str {
        self.human.name
    }
}
```

---

If your `Human` type can be made `Copy` (which behaves similarly to a [C# value type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/value-types)) then you can simplify matters by making `HumanToEmployeeAdapter` own the `Human`, which means you don't have to worry about the lifetimes of the references:

```
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
struct Human<'a> {
    name: &'a str,
}

trait Employee {
    fn id(&self) -> i32;
    fn name(&self) -> &str;
}

struct HumanToEmployeeAdapter<'a> {
    human: Human<'a>,
    id: i32,
}

impl<'a> HumanToEmployeeAdapter<'a> {
    fn new(id: i32, human: Human<'a>) -> Self {
        HumanToEmployeeAdapter { id, human }
    }
}

impl<'a> Employee for HumanToEmployeeAdapter<'a> {
    fn id(&self) -> i32 {
        self.id
    }

    fn name(&self) -> &str {
        self.human.name
    }
}
```

Note that you still need to track the lifetime of the `name` because `&str` is a reference. If you made it into an owned `String`, then you wouldn't need the lifetime parameter for `Human`, but then `Human` couldn't be `Copy`. That's because `String`s cannot be safely copied in memory, due to their `Drop` impl (similar to a [C# finalizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/destructors)), which would cause a double-free if Rust allowed you to do it - which is why it doesn't.

Comment: `human: &'a Human<'a>` — this is one place where Rust allows / requires you to make more decisions than a language like C#. For *this* specific example, storing a reference to the `Human` is overkill. You could just store it completely inline.

Comment: @Shepmaster If you already have the `Human` in use, and you need to pass it to a function that requires an `Employee`, then you may not want to move the original. As a general case, I think this is "better" and closer to what you'd expect in C#.

Comment: Sure, in general using a reference is the most compatible solution, but `Human` should implement `Copy`, rendering the "original" point moot. You could also directly take the `name` out of `Human` and store it in the adapter since `&str` is `Copy`.

Comment: @Shepmaster FWIW C# _does_ let you make the choice to store it inline.

Comment: Also, if the OP's real `Human` struct was just a `&str` I'd have expected them to just have said `&str` instead of bringing a struct into their MVCE. It's clearly very simplified compared to their real world problem.